# At first redirect to url and then change href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

This is my code I want, when I click to link at first redirect to page by link and then change href. The problem is when I click this href change but page don't change

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#product").click(function() {
    $('#product').attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
    $('#seller').attr('href', 'http://www.vmarket.com.vn/products.php?os=offer');
    $('#buy').attr('href', 'http://www.vmarket.com.vn/products.php?os=seeking');
  });

  $("#seller").click(function() {
    $('#product').attr('href', 'http://www.vmarket.com.vn/products.php');
    $('#seller').attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
    $('#buy').attr('href', 'http://www.vmarket.com.vn/products.php?os=seeking');
  });

  $("#buy").click(function() {
    $('#product').attr('href', 'http://www.vmarket.com.vn/products.php');
    $('#seller').attr('href', 'http://www.vmarket.com.vn/products.php?os=offer');
    $('#buy').attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="searchTabs">
  <li class="current">
    <a rel="nofollow" href="products.php" id="product">Sản phẩm</a>
  </li>
  <li class="tabRight">
    <a rel="nofollow" href="products.php?os=offer" id="seller">Cung</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a rel="nofollow" href="products.php?os=seeking" id="buy">Cầu</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please format your code instead of pasteing ultra-long one-line code.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to change the `href` attribute for the link?  Why don't you just redirect them straight away using:

```
window.location.href='/to/infinity/and/beyond';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand what you're trying to do.

The reason why it does not work is because when you click the links it will then as normal send the user to whatever that's inside the href. Looks like what you're looking for is a method of having the links change dynamically depending on which page you're on? Right?

I would suggest using a server side language to handle that. Using parameters to control what link to show.

For an example:

```
<ul id="searchTabs">
    <li class="current" >
        <a rel="nofollow" href="products.php" id="product">Sản phẩm</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tabRight">
        <a rel="nofollow" href="products.php?os=offer" id="seller">Cung</a>
    </li>
    <li >
        <a rel="nofollow" href="products.php?os=seeking" id="buy">Cầu</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Would become:

```
<ul id="searchTabs">
       <li class="current" >
          <a rel="nofollow" href="products.php?links=1" id="product">Sản phẩm</a>
      </li>
      <li class="tabRight">
          <a rel="nofollow" href="products.php?links=2" id="seller">Cung</a>
      </li>
      <li >
          <a rel="nofollow" href="products.php?links=3" id="buy">Cầu</a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Then you could with a server side language such as PHP do a switch on the link parameter. Then depending on what is set change the href attributes.

-

Reason why yours isn't working is because it redirect the user. Which means you're JavaScript won't matter at all as none of it have any influence on the other page.

You could prevent it from changing the actual location but it does not sound like that's what you're looking for. But just in case.. In order to prevent such event you can use:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#product").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#product').attr('href','javascript:void(0);');
        $('#seller').attr('href','http://www.vmarket.com.vn/products.php?os=offer');  
        $('#buy').attr('href','http://www.vmarket.com.vn/products.php?os=seeking');
    });

    $("#seller").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#product').attr('href','http://www.vmarket.com.vn/products.php');
        $('#seller').attr('href','javascript:void(0);');
        $('#buy').attr('href','http://www.vmarket.com.vn/products.php?os=seeking');
    });

    $("#buy").click(function() {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#product').attr('href','http://www.vmarket.com.vn/products.php');
        $('#seller').attr('href','http://www.vmarket.com.vn/products.php?os=offer');
        $('#buy').attr('href','javascript:void(0);');
    });
});
```

Hope that helps :) Leave a comment if there is anything you would like to explained.